# Why can't I render to a floating point texture in webgl?

Tags: webgl

I am creating a framebuffer and attaching a texture to it. Here is the texture that I would like to attach(but is not working):

`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R32F, sphere_texture.width, sphere_texture.height, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, null);`

However, when I use this as the texture format, it works:

`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, sphere_texture.width, sphere_texture.height, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)`

Does anyone know how I could render to a framebuffer float texture?

This is how I am creating the framebuffer:

```
framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, scale_factor_texture, 0);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,  null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WebGL2 contexts (which I assume you're working with, going by your intended use of the R32F format), you need to enable the [`EXT_color_buffer_float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EXT_color_buffer_float) extension for those formats to be renderable:

```js
if (!ctx.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float'))
    throw new Error('Rendering to floating point textures is not supported on this platform');
```

For WebGL1 context there's [`WEBGL_color_buffer_float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_color_buffer_float), as well as implicit support when enabling `OES_texture_float` (that one can probe for by attaching such a texture to render target and checking its completeness), however (with WebGL 1) rendering to single channel textures is not supported either way.

Comment: Rendering to a single channel texture is not supported at all? Because it doesn't give me an incomplete framebuffer error when I intialize the texture with this command:
```gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, sphere_texture.width, sphere_texture.height, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);```

Comment: for webgl **1** it's not. The code in your comment creates a three channel texture(RGB).